# How to prove divergence of this series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Evaluate $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^n$  prove that  $\displaystyle  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)$ diverges.

(Hint : use comparison test and $\displaystyle \sqrt[n]{n}=e^{\ln n/n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k!}(\frac{\ln n}{n})^{k}$ 
 without using l'Hôpital's rule.

I tried this

let y = $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^n$ then 
$lny = ln \displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^n$
$lny = \displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }nln(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)$ 
$lny = \displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }n \times \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } ln(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)$
$lny = \displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }n \times (ln \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } (\sqrt[n]{n}-1))$

I know that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } (\sqrt[n]{n}) = 1$ so,
$lny = \displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }n \times 0 = 0 $ Therefore $lny = 0 -> y=1$

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^n = 1$
is this right?

Comment: The sequence goes to zero. (can you prove it?)

Comment: What have you tried so far? You have a hint, did you give a shot at applying it?

Answer (score 2):

Hint for showing series divergence:

Define $a_n = n^{1/n}-1$.  Then $\ln n = n \ln(1+a_n) \leqslant na_n$, and

$$\frac{\ln n}{n} \leqslant a_n= n^{1/n} -1.$$

Apply the binomial theorem to show that sequence converges to $0$ (without using L'Hospital's rule).

Note that for $n \geqslant 2$,

$$n^{1/n} = 1 + a_n \geqslant 1 \implies n = (1 + a_n)^n \geqslant \frac{n(n-1)}{2}a_n^2 \implies a_n^2 \leqslant \frac{2}{n-1}.$$

Hence,

$$0 \leqslant a_n \leqslant \frac{2^{1/2}}{(n-1)^{1/2}},$$

and for $n \geqslant 4$

$$0 \leqslant (n^{1/n}-1)^n \leqslant \frac{2^{n/2}}{(n-1)^{n/2}} < \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n/2}.$$

Taking the limit and applying the squeeze principle we find $(n^{1/n}-1)^n \to 0$.

Comment: I have tried a method. please check my question I edited it.

Comment: With my hint or the Taylor series you mention we have $n^{1/n}-1 \geqslant \ln n /n > 1/n$ for $n \geqslant 3$  Hence the series diverges by comparing with the divergent harmonic series.  Your proof for the limit of the sequence is not correct.  Note that $\lim \ln (n^{1/n}-1) = -\infty \neq 0$.  Furthermore if $a_n \to \infty$ and $b_n \to 0$ then $a_nb_n$ does not necessarily converge to $0$, Consider $a_n = n^2$and $b_n = 1/n$.

Comment: I understand the divergent part and my fault (at limit question). Can you give me a hint to find the limit of $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^n$

Comment: @maXview: Expanded the answer above.

Comment: @maXview: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

By the binomial theorem,
for $n \ge 2$,

$(1+1/n)^n
=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\frac1{n^i}
=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{\prod_{j=0}^{i-1} (n-j)}{i!n^i}
\le \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{i!}
< e
$,
so
$1+1/n < e^{1/n}
< n^{1/n}$
for $n \ge 3$.

Therefore,
$n^{1/n}-1
> 1/n$
for $n \ge 3$,
so
$\sum_{n \ge 1} (n^{1/n}-1)
$ grows 
like $\sum 1/n$
at least,
and so diverges.

Note that
the key inequality is
$e^{1/n}
< n^{1/n}
$ for $n \ge 3$.
Ridiculous, isn't it?

Comment: Thank for the answer.
But I didn't get that point $e^{1/n}< n^{1/n}3$

Comment: It's just that this is such a crude inequality, but we need a lower bound for $n^{1/n}$ and we have a lower bound for $e^{1/n}$. It took me a while to realize that I could replace the constant $e$ with the variable $n$ to get what I wanted.

Comment: Oh, I got it now. Thank you.